# return rendered view with variables in component

Tags: cakephp

I'd like to have some layouts for messages in my `MessageComponent`.
Its `send` method should get an array of variables which used in view (layout) and render message with them, then send it..

The question is:

How to render a view (layout) with an array of variables in a component? and get rendered content instead of print it (in a component, too)

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(Edit: Misread your question)

If you want to get the HTML of a rendered view, simply do something like:

```
$view = new View($this, false);
$view->set(compact('foo', 'bar')); // set variables
$view->viewPath = 'elements'; // render an element
$html = $view->render('message'); // get the rendered markup
```

This should work in a controller as well as a component.

Comment: You can add this to not to get views warnings: ````$this->output = '';````